# Finitely generated ordered monoids and noetherian subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, monoid

Let $E$ be an additively written cancellable commutative monoid with no non-trivial units. We furnish $E$ with the order defined by "$x\leq y$ if and only if there exists $z\in E$ with $y=x+z$", so that it is an ordered monoid. If we consider a subset $F\subseteq E$, we can ask whether it is noetherian *as an ordered set,* i.e., whether every nonempty subset of $F$ has a maximal element.

It is not hard to see that if $E$ is finitely generated, then the noetherian subsets of $E$ are precisely the finite ones. So, we could ask for the converse: If the noetherian subsets of $E$ are precisely the finite ones, is then $E$ finitely generated?

I think this is *not true,* but was not able to come up with a counterexample. So, here is my question:

> What is an example of a monoid as above, but *not* finitely generated, whose noetherian subsets are precisely the finite ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile this was answered [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207541/11025). There, David Lampert showed that there is no such example.